# Determine cloud type on the picture

Tags: clouds, earth-observation

I'm struggling to determine a cloud type on the photo below (I assume it is a Cirrus cloud
and wind shear also depicted there, correct me if I'm wrong).
[image]

Comment: You may want to add a location so that one can look at satellite images around that time